# Is it matter if setting View alpha with alpha attribute or adding suitable value to background attribute?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, alpha

For some reason i can't understand when i want to set opacity of 0.6 to some view, so when i set the following code:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom_divider"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#9903a9f4"/>
```

and the following code:

```
 android:id="@+id/bottom_divider"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="#9903a9f4"
    android:alpha="0.6"/>
```

i get a **different colour** , ** althugh** *99* in the beginning of the background in hexa is equal to 255 multiple in 0.6 
can someone explain me why i get different colours in both codes?

Comment: If you using #99 you no need declare set alpha, below code change to `android:background="#03a9f4"` It will be same result

Comment: as Alpha is the opacity of the view. if you use background then its set view's background what ever you set, but when you set alpha is set opacity of view. so that you got diff color in both scenario.

Comment: @CôngHải, but if i set alpha, when adding 99 to "#03a9f4" it shouldn't make any change. isn't it?

Comment: @NagvadiyaVishal, sorry but i didn't understand you

Comment: Sure. When you setbackground with #99 and set alpha 0.6 result actuall is 0.6 * 0.6 = 0.36

Comment: @CôngHải thanks a lot!!!!!!